# 21:9 monitor taking squished screenshots

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, screenshot, widescreen

I have dual ultra wide [LG 21:9 Ultrawide 34WL500-B](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34WL500-B-ultrawide-monitor) monitors (native/default resolution 2560x1080px).

They mirror each other.

When I hit print screen and then I paste it to a paint document for example, it's completely squished horizontally ([example 1600x761px](https://postimg.cc/Kk6bCGxf)), as if the PC thought it was 1080 regular and tried to compensate.

I don't mean it only takes a 1920 screenshot, it's actually squished further. Unable to find any fix as of yet, lots of software and searching has produced the same results.

- RTX 2060 (not Super or Ti version)
- NVIDIA drivers detect 2560x1**9**80
- Windows detects display(s) at 2560x1**0**80

Monitors only have original and auto wide as options.

Comment: Is paint just resizing the image to fit the space available in the window? If you change the zoom to 100% is the image the correct resolution? A screenshot might help here.

Comment: Are you using DPI scaling on your monitors? I've found that that can mess with screenshots a bit

Comment: All screenshot programs do this, and no DPI scaling. Just 2560/1080p 100%

Comment: Could you post one such image?

Comment: Here https://i.postimg.cc/MHTGMHLC/IMG-20200302-WA0001.jpg

Comment: Questions: (1) Have you installed the [NVIDIA 442.50 driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/157539/en-us)? (2) What is your computer and is your adapter the RTX 2060 (not Super or Ti)? (3) What is the model of your monitors?

Comment: Yes, custom built i9-9900k, 2060 regular, LG 21:9 Ultrawide  34WL500-B

Comment: To be more specific: Do selection tools like the windows snipping tool do the same thing? What about screenshots of one specific window like a windowed Steam game vs fullscreen?

Comment: What is the resolution of the full image after it's pasted? and if you send one of the screenshot images to another PC/your phone, does it display correctly?

Comment: I don't know the resolution of the image exactly but obviously as soon as I upload it I do it in full quality so you can see in the link that's exactly the resolution and size/view. This also occurs using screenshot software of every kind. I'm going to have to try a steam game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please confirm the resolution set in Windows:**

1. Right-click on Desktop, Display Settings
2. Click Advanced display settings
3. Note the Resolution

**Take a screenshot with this method then compare resolution matches:**

1. Tap Print Screen (Prt Scn) button on your keyboard
2. Open Paint (mspaint from Start Menu)
3. Paste
4. Confirm resolution is the same

[image]

*You may not have the 'Classic' Paint program I have, but usually it will show SOMEWHERE the original resolution as many programs (Word, etc.) shrink them*

Either you had a typo in your question or the Nvidia is showing the wrong resolution (1**9**80px?) for the monitors. Windows shows the correct resolution for what those monitors support 2560x1**0**80px

---

**--EDIT:**
Your monitor can confirm what resolution it's receiving from the PC ([pg10/17 of owners manual](http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=Qcmlq8O5qeXUfBbUB5mFw)). This may help to confirm the issue IS NOT with the monitors, but instead with the PC or cables to monitors (which I think is likely)

1. **Push** the joystick **button**
2. Move joystick to highlight **'Settings'** & push it up/in to select
3. Highlight & choose **'General'**
4. Highlight & choose **'Information'**

Comment: How do I correct it because at the bottom of the paint it says 1922 by 1700 or something stupid so you found it.

Comment: My first numbered items shows how to do it, please confirm that. It's possible a graphics driver or cable could also be causing it, but lets start with the basics of verifying what Windows has your resolution set to

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the shortcut **Win + Shift + S** and then click on Capture Full Screen? If not, try it, it could help.

Also, instead of relying on Paint, try to **Win + Print Screen** it and it saves the screenshot directly to images/screenshots

Or **Win + W** and then Capture Full Screen